# Apostrophe in sqlite selection

Tags: android, sqlite

selection that works correctly:

```
selection: title LIKE '% Z %' OR title LIKE 'Z %' OR title LIKE '% Z'
```

My app crashes if db selection containes apostrophe:

Log:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'% ''": , 
while compiling: SELECT _id, title FROM table_name WHERE title LIKE '% ' %' 
OR title LIKE '' %' OR title LIKE '% ''
```

OR:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ZCUU": syntax error: , 
while compiling: SELECT _id, title FROM laws WHERE title LIKE '% ZCUU' %' 
OR title LIKE 'ZCUU' %' OR title LIKE '% ZCUU''
```

Who knows how to insert apostrophe in to search selection correctly? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a double apostrophe in your strings: ''

i.e.:

```
SELECT _id, title FROM laws WHERE title LIKE '% ZCUU'' %' OR title LIKE 'ZCUU'' %' OR title LIKE '% ZCUU'''
```

Answer (score 3):

Requesting content of the database that way lead to risks of SQL injections. You should use [query methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%29) that will manage apostrophes for you by the way.